# Numpy array, mask filling

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays a and b. a is shape (2,4) and b is shape (4,):

And I want to fill a third array h so that:

```
h = np.array([[a[0,0], a[1,2], 0, 0, a[0,2], a[0,3], 0],
              [a[1,0], a[2,2], 0, 0, a[1,2], a[1,3], 0],
              [  b[0],   b[1], 0, 0,   b[2],   b[3], 0]])
```

I currently do the following:

```
hs = np.hsplit(np.vstack((a, b)), 2)

h = np.zeros((3, 8))  # Allocate the array
h[:, 0:2] = hs[0]
h[:, 5:7] = hs[1]
```

Is there a more efficient (speed/memory wise) way to do it?

Thank you.

(edit): put indices for better comprehension

Comment: In general, how do you know where to put the zeros? You mention a mask, but where is the mask?

Comment: I know that, whatever a and b (fixed fimesions), I always have to get back:
[[a11, a12, 0, 0, a13, a14, 0],
 [a21, a22, 0, 0, a23, a24, 0],
 [  b1,   b2, 0, 0,   b3,   b4, 0]]

Comment: I'm sure you know. How do you specify? Mask? Indices? Are you asking?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I spoke about masks but for me it was a way to say "I want stuff there". I didn't know masks are a real thing. I am asking for a "fair" way to do the assignment of the array h. Mask or indices, whatever's the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two common ways of placing something along specific indices are indices and masks.

To use a mask, define something like

```
m = np.array([True, True, False, False, True, True, False])
```

Then you can do

```
h = np.zeros((a.shape[0] + b.shape[0], m.size))
h[:a.shape[0], m] = a
h[-b.shape[0]:, m] = b
```

To use indices, you do something similar, except you need to know the total size of your output:

```
i = [0, 1, 4, 5]
h = np.zeros((a.shape[0] + b.shape[0], 7))
h[:a.shape[0], i] = a
h[-b.shape[0]:, i] = b
```

In both cases, you can pre-stack the input, but that will not help you with time or memory:

```
x = np.concatenate((a, b[None, :]), axis=0)
h[:, m] = x
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without defining hs:

```
h = np.zeros((3, 7))
h[0:2,(0,1,4,5)] = a
h[2,(0,1,4,5)] = b
```

or without a and b:

```
h = np.zeros((3, 7))
h[0:2,(0,1,4,5)] = 1
h[2,(0,1,4,5)] = 2
```

output:

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [2. 2. 0. 0. 2. 2. 0.]]
```

Comment: although hardcoding is probably the fastest: `h = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],[2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]])`

Comment: I only get the values of a and b at runtime (sized is fixed, but they come from another algorithm).

Comment: Then the first option should work @Maltergate